# How to change background color of multiple link using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background-color of links according to the given array `colors`   using javascript and mainly using for loop and the parent-child selector of javascript/jquery. When I will reach the end of elements of colors array, I'll start with the first element of colors array.

Array for color `var colors = ['#607ec7', '#ca85ca', '#61c436', '#e54e7e', '#f4b23f', '#46c49c'];`

```js
<div class="vce-featured-section">
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: You've 6 colors in the array, but there are 9 `a` tags in the HTML. How should these be matched?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: start with the first one again when we reach the end of colors array @31piy

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this with JavaScript?  If the colors are static anyway, this is trivial with just CSS alone, using `nth-child` and similar.

Comment: Colors are static but we can add more links. So all newly added links should also get the color as defined in the array. Also, all adjacent links should have a different color. Answer by Ankit Agarwal solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `while` loop and for circular traversing of `color` array use `colors[i % colors.length]`:

```js
var colors = ['#607ec7', '#ca85ca', '#61c436', '#e54e7e', '#f4b23f', '#46c49c'];

var i=0;
var aElem = $('.vce-featured-section a');
while(i !== aElem.length){
  $(aElem[i]).css('background', colors[i % colors.length]);
  i++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vce-featured-section">
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
 </div>
```

**USING PURE JS**

```js
var colors = ['#607ec7', '#ca85ca', '#61c436', '#e54e7e', '#f4b23f', '#46c49c'];

var i=0;
var aElem = document.querySelectorAll('.vce-featured-section a');
while(i !== aElem.length){
  aElem[i].style.background = colors[i % colors.length];
  i++;
}
```

```html
<div class="vce-featured-section">
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a><br>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it worked. Can you help me with the same code in pure javascript?

Comment: @sachinmukherjee cool, edited the answer. Check it and let me know.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but the javascript code is not working.

Comment: @sachinmukherjee did you check the snippet? That works.

Comment: Yes, that worked on snippet but It's not working in my system. It's not throwing any error also.

Comment: @sachinmukherjee there might be other code that's conflicting

Answer (score 0):

```js
var colors = ['#607ec7', '#ca85ca', '#61c436', '#e54e7e', '#f4b23f', '#46c49c'];

for (i = 0; i <= colors.length; i++) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var t = document.createTextNode("ReraFirst Updates" + i);
    a.setAttribute("style", "background:" + colors[i] + "");
    a.setAttribute("href", "#");
    a.setAttribute("class", "category-97")
    a.appendChild(t);
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    document.body.appendChild(br);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help but I have used just dummy links in actual project these links will different. Can you help me with that using pure javascript?

Comment: @sachinmukherjee Sure :-)

Comment: @sachinmukherjee answer updated :-)  & this is pure javascript bro :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple .each loop to setup colors;

```
var colors = ['#607ec7', '#ca85ca', '#61c436', '#e54e7e', '#f4b23f', '#46c49c'];

var length = colors.length;
var currentColorIndex = 0;

$('.vce-featured-section a').each(function(index) {
  $(this).css('background-color', colors[currentColorIndex]);
  currentColorIndex = ++currentColorIndex % length;
});

<div class="vce-featured-section">
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
   <a href="#" class="category-97">ReraFirst Updates</a>
 </div>
```